# Ansible: How to ensure that the fail2ban service is enabled on the remote server?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, systemd, fail2ban

This is my task.

```yaml
- name: Ensure fail2ban is running and enabled.
  ansible.builtin.service:
   name: fail2ban
   state: started
   enabled: true
```

I am getting this error.

```
'fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "get_service_tools not implemented on target platform"}'
```

Need help!!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since the error message states `get_service_tools not implemented on target platform`, what is your target platform?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 @U880D

Comment: Please append output of `ansible -i inventory <your_server> -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*,ansible_service_mgr"` to your question post.

Comment: Hover over the systemd and fail2ban tags and read those popups. Both topics are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting this error because I was trying to execute on my local which is Mac OS.

```
    when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
```

I have used this condition so that it will only execute when the target platform is of Debian.

Answer (score 0):

The [`service` module – Manage services](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) is just

> *a proxy for multiple more specific service manager modules (such as [`ansible.builtin.systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-systemd-module) and [`ansible.builtin.sysvinit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sysvinit_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-sysvinit-module)).*

and

> *Controls services on remote hosts. Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart.*

According the source code [`ansible/modules/service.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service.py) the error message

```
get_service_tools not implemented on target platform
```

shouldn't happen for systems with `systemd`, but in example for `launchd`. See Ansible Issue #[10412](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10412) "*Ansible OSX `get_service_tools` not implemented on target platform*".

So you could try with [`systemd` module – Manage systemd units](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) and if `fail2ban` has a `fail2ban.service` file implemented correctly.